# Please help me make sense of this "BinarySearchCountAll" method in my book

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree

My book [C# 3.0 Cookbook by O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516109.do) has the following example which is confusing me. (Exact transcription below.)

```
// Count the number of times an item appears in the sort List<T>.
public static int BinarySearchCountAll<T>(this List<T> myList, T searchValue)
{
   // Search for the first item.
   int center = myList.BinarySearch(searchValue);
   int left = center;
   while (left < 0 && myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue))
   {
     left -= 1;
   }
   int right = center;
   while (right < (myList.Count - 1) && myList[right+1].Equals(searchValue))
   {
     right += 1;
   }    
   return (right - left) + 1;
}
```

In particular, I am confused starting at the

```
int center = myList.BinarySearch(searchValue);
int left = center;
while (left < 0 && myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue))
```

snippet. According to [the documentation on the BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) method, `left` is the index of the element. So how does the condition

```
left < 0 && myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue)
```

in the `while` loop make any sense? Because of short-circuiting, if `left < 0` then right side `myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue)` is evaluated but `myList[left-1]` is accessing a negative index! Right?

I did read the part about what happens in BinarySearch if the element is not found

> a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the
>   next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger
>   element, the bitwise complement of Count.

and I can't figure out if this method in my book is trying to leverage that fact. Seems like a really confusing way of writing what should be a simple method, or else I'm not understanding it correctly. Because if I understanding correctly that `BinarySearch` returns an arbitrary first matching element found then I don't understanding why the method couldn't just be

```
// Count the number of times an item appears in the sort List<T>.
public static int BinarySearchCountAll<T>(this List<T> myList, T searchValue)
{
   int count = 0,
   int center = myList.BinarySearch(searchValue);
   if ( center < 0 ) return count; 
   for ( int k = center + 1; k < myList.Length - 1 && myList[k] = searchValue; ++k ) 
      ++count;  
   for ( int k = center - 1; k >=0 && myList[k] = searchValue; --k ) 
      ++count;
   return count; 
}
```

Comment: Note that the worst case complexity of the method could be O(n).
It would be so when all the elements of the list are same.

Comment: There was an [errata item](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596516109) reported for this on Dec 1, 2010, but it wasn't officially confirmed by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct

```
while (left < 0 && myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue))
```

should be

```
while (left > 0 && myList[left-1].Equals(searchValue))
```

instead. 
Notice the symmetry for the right: while (right < (myList.Count - 1).... Naturally insinuating it should be greater than for the left.

The BinarySearchCountAll method finds an index "center" where center=searchValue. Since list is sorted it can simply traverse the adjacent elements until they do not equal "center". Then, it returns the amount of equal "center" elements